# How can I create a user object in a custom form and save it?

Tags: 7, forms, users

Basically, I want to create a user object in a custom form and save it in the database.

This is my custom form and its handlers.

```php
function registerme_newform($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['account details'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Account Details'),
    '#description' => t('Enter Personal Credentials'),
  );

  $form['account details']['first name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('First Name'),
    '#default_value' => t('Be sure of your first name'),
    '#attributes' => array(
    'onblur' => "if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Be sure of your first name'}",
    'onfocus' => "if (this.value == 'Be sure of your first name') {this.value = ''}", 
    ), 
  ); 

  $form['account details']['last name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Last Name'),
    '#default_value' => t('Be sure of your last name'),
    '#attributes' => array(
    'onblur' => "if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Be sure of your last name'}",
    'onfocus' => "if (this.value == 'Be sure of your last name') {this.value = ''}",
    ),
  );
    
  $form['account details']['email'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('E-Mail'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => t('Email acts as username.Do not forget it!'),
    '#attributes' => array(
    'onblur' => "if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email acts as username. Do not forget it!'}",
    'onfocus' => "if (this.value == 'Email acts as username. Do not forget it!') {this.value = ''}", 
    ), 
  );

  $form['account details']['password'] = array(
    '#type' => 'password',
    '#title' => t('Password'),
    '#maxlength' => 60,
    '#size' => 60,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#description' => t('Password should be at least 6 characters long.'),
  );

  $form['home'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => 'Home Address',
    '#description' => t('Enter Personal Residential Credentials'),
  );

  $form['home']['street'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Street Address',
  );

  $form['home']['city'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'City',
  );
 
  $form['work'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => 'Work Address',
    '#description' => t('Enter Official Address'),
  );
 
  $form['work']['street'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Street Address',
  );

  $form['work']['city'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'City',
  );
 
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Register Me'),
  );

  return $form;
}

function registerme_newform_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['values']['account details']['first name'] == 'Be sure of your first name') {
    form_set_error('first name',t('Please enter your first name'));
  }
}

function registerme_newform_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  dsm($form_state);
}
```

Is `user_save()` the correct function to save a user object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you should use to create a new user account in the form submission handler is similar to the following one.

```php
$account = new stdClass();
$account->is_new = TRUE;

$edit = array(
  'name' => $username,
  'pass' => $form_state['values']['password'],
  'mail' => $form_state['values']['email'],
  'init' => $form_state['values']['email'],
  'status' => 1,
  'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
  'field_fname' => $form_state['values']['first name'],
  'field_lname' => $form_state['values']['last name'],
);

user_save($account, $edit);
```

The form shown in the question does not request a username. Replace `$username` in the code with the correct value.

Setting `$account->is_new` is important, or Drupal will not create a new account.

As side note, a validation handler does not need to check that a required value has been submitted, since that is done from Drupal core.
Instead of using JavaScript code to set the initial value for a field, you should use that value as placeholder: a value that is shown as guideline before users enter a value in the field. That should be done if it does not repeat information already given in the form element description, for example.

```php
$form['account details']['email'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('E-Mail'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#default_value' => "",
  '#description' => t('Email acts as username. Do not forget it!')
  '#attributes' => array(
    'placeholder' => t("Your email"),
  ), 
);
```

Also, the default value for a form element should be either a value previously entered for the same form, from the same user, or an empty value. It should not be a value like `t('Email acts as username. Do not forget it!')` which then forces you to check if that is the submitted value and return an error from the validation handler. It could also confuse users who can think the form is prefilling the form element for them, while it is giving a description for the form element, which should instead be shown as `#description`.